# Why doesn't a blank cell in excel evaluate to false?

Tags: excel

A blank cell evaluates to each of the following:

[image]

When then does `OR(A1,A1)` evaluate to an error, when `A1` is equivalent to (or coerced to) both `0` and `FALSE`? Is this a known inconsistency, or what's the reason for this behavior in Excel?

Comment: Blank cells treated as zero `0`. Zero means false in Boolean logic. When you are using `OR(A1,A1)` then it is giving error due to `0` is treated as number and OR expect Boolean value. Try `=OR(--A1,--A1)` which will give you `FALSE` as result.

Comment: as @Harun24hr mentioned  or to use a boolean condition for testing blanks: `=OR(A1="",A1="")`

Comment: @Harun24hr what do you mean? Look at cell C6, `=OR(0,0)` evaluates to false.

Comment: @David542 different scenario. 2 numbers can be evaluated by a boolean condition, 2 different data types cannot.

Comment: the scenario you have for `OR(A1,A1)` is equivalent to this one: `OR("","")` this input is a string, so it cannot coerce to a boolean value.

Comment: @jwenting what are the two different data types? The two operands are `A1` and `A1`. Additionally, try doing `OR(A1)` -- this will also fail.

Comment: @DavidLeal I think this is the only answer/comment I've read that makes sense so far. Why then is the blank cell evaluated to `""` in this context and not `false` or `0` ?

Comment: there are two ways to check a cell is blank: `ISBLANK(A1)` or `A1=""`. The first checks for blank, the second for nothing. Check this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-if-to-check-if-a-cell-is-blank-dff4eda1-6187-4b83-b7f6-4c3c0a1e2188). There are other situations where you can test for blanks, but through an implicit conversion of a binary operation, for example: `A1=0`, `A1=FALSE` but these are indirect ways, thanks coercion of the binary operator, but for `OR(A1,A1)` there is not such binary operation to force a coercion.  Excel sometimes is a mystery, :-)

Comment: A formal explanation is what is stated in the [OR](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/or-function-7d17ad14-8700-4281-b308-00b131e22af0) documentation: *"If an array or reference argument contains text or empty cells, those values are ignored"*, therefore for this case `OR(A1,A1)` it ignores both input arguments, so there is no logical condition to test and this it what it states for this case: *"If the specified range contains no logical values, OR returns the #VALUE! error value."*

Comment: @David542 check my response adding more details based on my last comment. I hope it helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just answering the question based on my response in the comment section of the question. The case: `OR(A1,A1)` returns `#VALUE!` can be explained looking at [OR](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/or-function-7d17ad14-8700-4281-b308-00b131e22af0) documentation. Here is the `OR` syntax:

```
OR(logical1, [logical2], ...)
```

It expects a logical condition for each input argument that can evaluate to either `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

In the **Remark** section of the referred documentation indicates the `OR` behavior for empty cells:

> If an array or reference argument contains text or **empty cells**, those values are ignored.

In our case `A1` is an empty cell, therefore both input argument are **ignored**.

In another remark item, Microsoft states:

> If the specified range contains no logical values, `OR` returns the `#VALUE!` error value.

which explains why for this case it returns `#VALUE!`, i.e. none of the input arguments are logical values. For example: `OR(A1,A1,1=1)` returns `TRUE`, because the first two input arguments are ignored, but the last one evaluates to `TRUE`. Since blank cells and texts are treated the same way, the behavior of `OR(A1,A1)` for the case of blanks is equivalent to `OR("","")`.

If you want to return a valid value for this case, we can use one of the following options:

```
OR(ISBLANK(A1), ISBLANK(A1)) -> testing for blanks
OR(A1="", A1="") -> testing for nothing
```

Check this link: [Using IF to check if a cell is blank](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-if-to-check-if-a-cell-is-blank-dff4eda1-6187-4b83-b7f6-4c3c0a1e2188). You can also use `LEN` function, i.e. `OR(LEN(A1)=0, LEN(A1)=0)` as it is suggested by [Exceljet](https://exceljet.net/functions/isblank-function). Remember testing for nothing is **different** than testing for blanks. If `A1` has the value `=""` (or any formula that returns `""`)  then `ISBLANK(A1)` function returns `FALSE`, but `A1=""` returns `TRUE`.

The case `OR(0,0)` is different, it returns `FALSE` because Excel treats `0` as `FALSE`, it does an implicit conversion, coercing the `0` value to `FALSE`.

Answer (score -1):

The 2 cells you're trying to compare are of different data types. There is no OR(NUMERIC, BOOLEAN) function therefore you get an error/undefined result.

Comment: how do you know they are of different types? They are literally the same cell -- `=AND(A1, A1)`. Isn't `A1` by definition the same type as `A1` ?